# How to randomly assign each observation to one of two labels

Tags: r, sample

I have a data matrix in R as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    0    4
[4,]    5    1
[5,]    6    2
[6,]    4    0
```

Now I want to randomly assign each observation to either 1 or 0 cluster. Basically I am trying to do Kmeans and before that I wanted to initialise each observation to some cluster.

I want to use sample function in R. But I am not sure how sample would give this. Sample function is to get a sample from a set.

Can someone guide?

Comment: May be `matrix(sample(0:1, length(m1), replace=TRUE), ncol=2)` or use `rbinom`

Comment: No. See what I want is like one new col which assigns each observation as either 1 or zero. Like assign each observation into one of two clusters randomly

Comment: Not sure I understand you properly.  May be you need `split`.  `split(m1,sample(0:1, length(m1), replace=TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sample in the following way to generate a random sequence of 0 or 1s:

```
sample(c(0,1), size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
```

To add this to your matrix you can use `cbind()`, so maybe something like this will do what you want:

```
data = matrix(data = 1:6, ncol = 2, nrow = 6)
newData = cbind(data, sample(c(0,1), size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE))
```